# How to call UpdateCellsRequest in Google Sheets script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to fix my Google Sheets script program which is timing out. I am merging a set of sheets that consist of a grid of letters that are highlighted with colours to identify shapes in the grid. I want to show a heat map and also have sheets of specific grouping of the individual shapes.
I works but times out once I started adding lots of the individual shapes sheets, so I've fixed it to get everything ready and then call batchUpdate of some description. Is this possible ?. Can I batch up a series of set background colour and set bold and italic on a series of individual cells in one call within scripts ?.
Below is my code, how do I call UpdateCellsRequest()

```
    function createBatchMerge(target_name){
//  var range=lookup[target_name].getRange('A2:S9')
  for (const target_name in merge_store){
    var sheetId=lookup[target_name].getSheetId()
    var instructions=merge_store[target_name]
    for (const cellc in instructions){
      var instruction=instructions[cellc]
//      Logger.log("CELLC="+cellc)
      var [row,col]=cellc.split(':')
//      Logger.log("ROW="+row+" col="+col)
      var i={
        updateCells:{
          rows:[{
            values:[{
                "userEnteredFormat": {
                  backgroundColor:instruction.colour,
                  textFormat:{
                    italic:instruction.italic,
                    bold:instruction.bold
                  },
                  note:instruction.names.join(',')
                }
              }
            ]
          }]
        },
        start:{
          "sheetId": sheetId,
          "rowIndex": 1+row,
          "columnIndex": col
        }
      }
      jobs.push(i)
    }
  }
}

function dumpMerge(){
//  Logger.log(jobs)
  SpreadsheetApp.UpdateCellsRequest(jobs)
}
```

Here is my sheet. I need it to work in the associated script so I can allow collaborators to update the shapes and add new ones and then just run it.
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11bROsFF8hM9SHJtH4WewxnuZ1Z9tuB8JUFR5MM7Ga7o/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes it is possible: [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest) >RowData >CellData >UserEnteredFormat

Comment: https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate doesn't list a script.gs example, which is why I wondered if I'd coded for nothing.

Comment: Enable sheets api and use `Sheets` instead of `Spreadsheet`. You can also search samples here based on the documentation url like this https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+is%3Aa+url%3Ahttps%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Fsheets%2Fapi%2Freference%2Frest%2Fv4%2Fspreadsheets%2Frequest%23updatecellsrequest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issues:

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app) doesn't have any `UpdateCellsRequest` method. If you want to call [UpdateCellsRequest](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#updatecellsrequest), enable [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) (see [how to enable](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services)).
- You are not providing a valid request body: (1) it should include a [`requests` field](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate#request-body), (2) it should include a `fields` field (see [here](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#UpdateCellsRequest)), (3) `note` is not a valid field; I'm not sure what information you want to update here, but it should be added to a different field.

#### Solution:

Taking all this into account, a possible request body is provided below. Please note that this might not satisfy all your purposes, since it's not clear what exact information you want to update. In any case, it may work as a guide.

#### Code sample:

```
const payload = {
  requests: [
    {
      updateCells: {
        rows:[{
          values:[{
            userEnteredFormat: {
              textFormat: {
                italic: instruction.italic,
                bold: instruction.bold
              }
            }        
          }]
        }],
        start: { 
          sheetId: sheetId,
          rowIndex: 1+row,
          columnIndex: col
        },
        fields: "userEnteredFormat.textFormat" // Fields you want to update
      }
    }
  ]
}
const spreadsheetId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(payload, spreadsheetId);
```

Comment: I am not surprised the instruction block was wrong, I was just getting to the debugging bit and couldn't fathom this.

Comment: thanks again. rgb colours need to be scaled 0-1, which is not what getRed etc do, they give 0-255. And if they are null you will get an exception that it cant find the batchupdate method, fields needed to be "userEnteredFormat(backgroundColor,textFormat),note"

Comment: @MarkLester I'm not sure where you get `getRed` from, but you need to provide rgb colors between 0 and 1, inside the `backgroundColor` field.

Comment: @lamblichus  I'm up. There are getRed/Green/Blue methods in the Color class, but I just hack my own from the html hex string and divide by 255. I've moved on to the more interesting job of the geometry on the first page of this incredible work of art. I was hoping to be able to draw directly onto a google drawing but there appears to be no api. I am back to outputting csv files and dragging into gimp. Many thanks indeed. It was the installation of the api that was really screwing me but having a nice JSON example helped a lot too.